# C# Running a Task in a specified UIThread (not the continuation) blocks when the ThreadUI goes to sleep

Tags: c#, timeout, task, blocking, ui-thread

I'm developing an application that requires to make calls to different servers: some of them are ActiveX(or COM) servers, other can run in a ThreadPool. Since the providers of these servers are from different companies and some of them are using (really) old technologies (C/C++ dlls wrapped on .Net ) they don't have a consistent (if not at all) timeout mechanism.

I started to implement the async call using Task and the Timeout suggested on different articles (thanks to Reed Copsey, Jr., Stephen Toub, and Stephen Cleary).

In the "client" side (for test app is the MainForm) I have:

int result = await sB.TheForm.F2Async("TEST", 1.5, combinedCTS);

where:

```
    - sB.TheForm: is the WinForm that runs in the second UIThread. The MainForm spun the "TheForm" Form in a different thread making an UIThread.
    - "TEST", 1.5: are the actual parameters 
    - combinedCTS is of CancellationTokenSource type
```

On the "server" side, the F2Async function schedules the F2 function in the second UIThread as a TASK (workingTask), and quickly and asynchronously :) schedules the

```
var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(workingTask, Task.Delay(nTimeoutMilisec));
```

To schedule the Task in a different UI Thread I'm using:

```
var workingTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(
                  () => F2(s1, d1), 
                  combinedCTS.Token, 
                  TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, 
                  TaskSchedulerForm);
```

where:

```
    - F2() is the synchronous function (the ActiveX function)
    - TaskSchedulerForm: is initialized in the LOAD event handler of the second UIThread as
TaskSchedulerForm = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
```

If F2 function goes to sleep (or blocks) WHY the Task.Factory.StartNew blocks?

since there is no await on the call of the StartNew (the function F2Async) the code should continue in the main thread ui until the await of the WhenAny  tasks.

I tried different was to get to run the `await Task.WhenAny(...)`. When the F2 blocks the statement after RunNew will be executed only after the F2 completes.

The F2 runs the the second (desired) UI Thread. If the function F2 is not blocking then it is still running when the Task.WhenAny is starting to await - which is good because now I can force the continuation to run in case of an timeout.